I have a function: a(t) = \[ 2 + \cos\left(3t + \frac{\pi}{2}\right) + 3\sin\left(3t + \frac{\pi}{2}\right). \]
I am having a hard time determining the fundamental frequency, as both sinusoidal terms have a frequency of 3. I have tried breaking them down into their respective e forms, but I'm still unsure how to proceed. My best guess is that I need to combine the terms in some way. Could someone help me understand the correct approach?
I have to also create the magnitude and phase graph and if they are both at 3, then I would think its not possible to plot a ½ as well as a 3/2j on the same k.

Small remark - that's not an equation (no equals sign), it's just a function. Possible suggestion: write as one sinusoid.

@SeanRoberson I apologize it is supposed to read as a(t) = .... I will change now

@JohnOmielan By adding pi/2 to the cosine term?

Note that $$A\sin(\alpha+\beta) = A\sin\alpha\cos\beta + A\cos\alpha\sin\beta$$ so if $\beta = 3t+\pi/2$, you need to solve for $A$ and $\alpha$ such that $A\sin\alpha = 1$ and $A\cos\alpha = 3$.

The fundamental frequency of a Fourier series is not affected by the phase. The period is $T=\frac{2 \pi}{3}$ so the fundamental frequency of the Fourier series is $f=\frac{1}{T}=\frac{3}{2 \pi}$.

The fundamental frequency of a Fourier series is not affected by the phase. The period is $T=\frac{2 \pi}{3}$ so the fundamental frequency of the Fourier series is $f=\frac{1}{T}=\frac{3}{2 \pi}$.

The function
$$a(t)=2+3 \sin\left(3 t+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)+\cos\left(3 t+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\tag{1}$$
simplifies to
$$a(t)=2+3 \cos(3 t)-\sin(3 t)\tag{2}$$
which is equivalent to
$$a(t)=2+\frac{3-i}{2} e^{-3 i t}+\frac{3+i}{2} e^{3 i t}\tag{3}$$
in exponential form.

The Fourier transform of $a(t)$ is
$$\hat{a}(f)=\mathcal{F}_t[a(t)](f)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} a(t)\, e^{-i 2 \pi f t} \, dt\\=2\, \delta(f)+\frac{3-i}{2}\, \delta\left(f+\frac{3}{2 \pi}\right)+\frac{3+i}{2}\, \delta\left(f-\frac{3}{2 \pi}\right)\tag{4}$$
which is consistent with $f=\frac{3}{2 \pi}$ mentioned above.

Note that $\left|\frac{3+i}{2}\right|=\left|\frac{3-i}{2}\right|=\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}$ and $\arg\left(\frac{3+i}{2}\right)=-\arg\left(\frac{3-i}{2}\right)=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)$ which suggests $a(t)$ can be evaluated as
$$a(t)=2+2\, \sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}\, \cos\left(3 t+\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\right)\tag{5}$$
